# node-red subflow with configuration parameters

Tags: node-red

So what we want is to have a subflow that can have some configuration parameters so that the instance can make use of those parameters in several of the subflow's nodes. Sounds like something that might be very useful in general. I really can't find any way to to this.

One possible solution would be to put the configuration in the message going to the input of the flow. Which might work, but what if there is no input, or the input is only part of the flow.

for instance, the topic name of an mqtt topic, that you would like to be different for ever instance of the subflow.

Comment: Hi, this sounds like a feature request rather than a typical StackOverflow question. Please use the node-red mailing list or slack channel (lined from nodered.org) to raise this with the community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as knolleary said, this is a feature request not a technical question

Comment: I don't know if there is some way to implement this using standard functionality. That's why I'm asking

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like it can be done currently but this feature is in development as Subflow Instance Properties.

https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Design:-Subflow-Instance-properties